# Select Rows individually in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have approximately 200 filled rows in my spreadsheet. Between every row, I want two empty rows. I wish to select each of these rows individually, right click>insert, repeat the same again, and my task is done. But, I cannot consume time selecting each row individually. Is there a way to do this? I am talking about 'individual rows', that is when you keep pressing the control button and click on row 1, then row 2, row 3 and so on. 
Not the case where I start the selection at row 1 and drag the entire selection till row 200.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, create a macro. If you haven't use a macro, then you will first need to turn down the security setting to allow macros to run.

The easiest way to create a macro is to record it. Select Tools, Macro, Record.

Select {Insert, Rows} twice, move the cursor down to where you want the next inserted row.

Select Tools, Macro, Stop. Give the macro a name and then under Manage Macros, you can assign a hot-key. Then you just need to press the hot-key every time you want 2 rows inserted.

Comment: +1. And make sure that 'Use Relative References' is ON before you record the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that would have worked at the time, though it would need Word for the intermediate step, or another editor capable of the action, would be to create a Named Range with the lines defined individually (so `1:1,2:2,3:3` and so on, not `1:3`), then select that Named Range and begin inserting rows, two in this case.

Two parts, the first is to create the Named Range which needs a `Refers to:` that looks like:

```
=Sheet1!$1:$1,Sheet1!$2$2,Sheet1!$3$3,Sheet1!$4$4,Sheet1!$5$5
```

Excel will happily take `=1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5` and convert it to the above. So that's all one need produce.

Nowadays (2022), creating such a string is the work of 30 seconds. Back in 2014, one only had `CONCATENATE` and "AND-ing" to work with. Hence the need for the other, intermediate, program. (Arguably, VBA is a wholly different program from Excel, so conceptually, this is no "worse" than a macro as it too simply requires a separate program for a step.) Excel can create the components easily, and those can be copied and pasted appropriately into Word which can then easily remove the line feed from their ends giving you a nice string to place into the Named Range.

Just pick a column, even insert one for a moment or open another spreadsheet to do it in, highlight as many cells, in a single column, starting with a cell in the 2nd row you need to work with, as needed to have one for each row you need to do the inserting between, be sure the first of them is selected, place `=ROW()&":"&ROW()&","` into the formula editor and press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`. (This is a "CSE" formula.) It will populate down the column's selected cells.

So, in practice, say you need to insert two rows under row 34 (in the end, they will become rows 35 and 36 while original row 35 will become row 37) and for four more original rows. What I'm showing will insert rows ABOVE the first "declared" row, so you need a string starting with "35" not "34":  to wit, `35:35,36:36,37:37,38:38,39:39`. (In the example, the last set of rows will go above row 39 ((last in the string)) which is where they are needed.) So you pick a column that has space, select its row 35 cell, and highlight the next four cells as well. Press `F2-Edit` and type the formula from above, then press `CSE` to get it placed. Those cells will now show the five pieces of `35:35,36:36,37:37,38:38,39:39`:  `35:35,` and so on.

How to get them together? Well, that's the trouble. Typing `CONCATENATE(F35,F36,F37,F38,F39)` is just as obnoxious as clicking each row separately. With them still highlighted though, copy them to the Clipboard, then move to a bare document in Word. Paste as Text Only. you now have something like:

35:35,
36:36,
37:37,
38:38,
39:39

Use Word's `Find and Replace` function. In it, select `More` in the lower left corner, then at the bottom, click `Special`. The very first choice ("Paragraph Mark") is the one you need. Click `Replace All` and now you have your string.

Copy it to the Clipboard (`Ctrl-A` makes sure you get it all) and return to Excel. In Excel again, bring up the Named Range function and create a new Named Range. Give it a name, then move to the `Refers to:` box at the bottom and type the `=` then paste that string. Close the function's dialogs, saving the Name as you go.

Now select the Named Range from the box left of the first line of the Formula Editor. After you click on it, all the row selecting will be done. Immediately right-click on the row labels at the very left and then click `Insert` to insert the first row. Do it again to insert the second row.

Now get rid of all the dross:  The material you created in the column you used (however appropriate for how you picked a column), the Named Range, and the Word document you have open.

Describing it all took a while, and I'm sure a while for anyone here to read. DOING it though took perhaps a MINUTE.

Nowadays (2022), the string would be simplicity itself, and then the Named Range is too, of course, with no `CSE` entry even required, and one can nowadays even make selecting (highlighting) the Named Range a matter of typing (say the Named Range is "horse") `=horse` into a blank cell, pressing Enter, then double-clicking on the cell with that formula to do the selection. If using the Name Box, as above, seems to weird for words (who ever even heard of that thing, right?). But still very doable in 2014. And for those who still have 2013, 2010, 2007, and maybe so on.